# Java: strange anomaly when printing int[]

Tags: java, arrays, string, printing, int

When I try to concatenate elements from a int[] that is a member of a class into a String, it works fine. But when I do the same procedure with a temp int[] (generated from Arrays.copyOf), I get jibberish. I don't understand why this is happening. A boiled down version of my code goes like this:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Test {

    public int[] arr;                       

    public Test(int[] arr) {                                             
        this.arr = arr;                                                        
    }

    public void fn() {
        // ...
        int[] temp = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length);
        System.out.println(this);
        System.out.println(temp);
    }                                                                       

    /*
     * Takes an integer array as input and returns a string representation
     * of the elements in the array.
     */
    public String arrayToString(int[] arr) {
        String s = "[";
        int i = 0;
        while(i < (arr.length - 1)) {
            s = s + arr[i++] + ", ";
        }
        s = s + arr[i] + "]";
        return s;
    }

    public String toString() {                                              
        return arrayToString(this.arr);                                     
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4};
        Test test = new Test(arr);
        test.fn();
        /*
         * Produces result:
         * [1, 2, 3, 4]
         * [I@3343c8b3
         */
    }
}
```

Why does this happen? As far as I can tell, both arr and temp should be of type int[].

Comment: In the future, please post your "gibberish"; I suspect that it's something like `[I@502a3135` (insert your own hex after the `@`), which is characteristic of accidentally printing an array reference instead of formatting it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your local copy is going via `arrayToString()` because you `println(this)` which invokes `toString()`.

Your temp copy is just trying to dump the `int[]` - try using `arrayToString(temp)` instead of `println(temp)`.

Comment: Oh. Wow. That was a clumsy mistake. I can't believe I got all the way to posting on Stack Overflow without realizing.... Thank you. :/

Answer (score 2):

This is unnecessary:

```
public String toString() {                                              
    return arrayToString(this.arr);                                     
}
```

but you could replace it with:

```
public String toString() {                                              
    return Arrays.toString(this.arr);                                     
}
```